# react-native async function returns promise but not my json data?

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I'm learning react-native, and I'm running into an issue. Why does getting data on return from an async function return a promise, but in the async function itself, it correctly returns an array of objects?

On `componentDidMount()`, I call my async function which in turn does a fetch to an api url:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    let data = this.getData();
    console.log(data);    // <-- Promise {_40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null}
    this.setState({
      dataSource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(data),
    })  
  }

  async getData() {
    const response = await fetch("http://10.0.2.2:3000/users", {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }   
        }); 
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);     // <-- (5) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
    return json;
  }
```

In `console.log(json)`, I get the correct list of json objects, and I can access them with `json[0].name`. But later, `console.log(data)` returns a promise with odd data:

```
Promise {_40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null}
```

... and I can no longer find my json objects. Why is this? More importantly, how can I retrieve my json data in `componentDidMount()` so that I can set it as the `dataSource`?

Comment: `async` functions return promises. `await` magically "unwraps" that promise. `let data = this.getData();` doesn't (and cannot use) `await`, so you have to handle the promise the "normal" way. If you are not familiar with promises I recommend to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises (this has nothing to do with react native btw, that's JavaScript).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since `getData()` is a promise, you should be able to obtain the data in a `then` block as follows:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.getData()
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({
        dataSource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(data),
      })  
    });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Another approach similar to the original code of the questioner:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    let data = await this.getData();
    console.log(data);    
    this.setState({
      dataSource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(data),
    })  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or another way is

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    const { data: dataSource = [] } = await this.getData();   
    this.setState({dataSource})  
  }
```

This will copy your data to a inmutable object an reasign the name, also, set a default value to the object `dataSource`