# object object returns react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to get data from AsyncStorage, but it returns object object, how I can return data normally?
If i return data in console.log() all is ok, but when I call function it returns object object.

Thanks

```
const getTheme = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('theme');
    console.log(value);   // returns dark 
   return JSON.stringify(value)
  } catch (error) {
    alert(error)
  }
};

alert(getTheme()) // [object, object]

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: Home,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        tabBarLabel: "Home",
        tabBarVisible: getActiveRoute(navigation.state) !== "ArticleScreen",
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon name="ios-home" color={tintColor} size={24} />
        )
      })
    },

    Courses: {
      screen: Courses,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Courses",
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon name="ios-school" color={tintColor} size={24} />
        )
      }
    }
  },
  {}
)

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <TabNavigator />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to stringify it?

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(apiRequest1));
```

[MDN stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

-----According to your new update----
You have got dark(A theme?) from data?

You could try something like:

```
const getTheme = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('theme');
    console.log(value);   // returns dark (Is here a theme?)
   return value  //Just retrun the value of dark?
  } catch (error) {
    alert(error)
  }
};

alert(getTheme) //Is here have to use getTheme not getTheme()?
```

You could try it.

Comment: it return {"_40":0,"_65":0,"_55":null,"_72":null}
What is this?

Comment: This should be promise from async

Comment: You could read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45200723/react-native-async-function-returns-promise-but-not-my-json-data)

Comment: i made like this const getTheme = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('theme');
    return value
  } catch (error) {
    alert(error)
  }
};