# Returning promise instead of data

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

In the following code I wrote to get data from an API, I am getting promises as an output instead of data. What am I missing? Can someone please help?

```
const axios = require('axios');

const ageFinder = async (userName) => {

    try {
        let userDetails =await axios.get(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/user/${userName}.json`)
        let user =userDetails.data
        return user
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err.message)
    }
}

console.log(ageFinder("someUser"))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-native async function returns promise but not my json data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45200723/react-native-async-function-returns-promise-but-not-my-json-data) An async function always return a promise. The answers to the linked Q&A should give you a sense of what you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [MDN page on async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), any function declared `async` returns a promise, which resolves whatever the function `returns` or rejects with an error, if any is encountered within the function (see "Return Value" section of page linked above).

So you will need to put your function call `ageFinder("someUser")` in another async function and `await` its result before logging, or you may use `.then()`.

Comment: I followed the steps you suggested. However, its still doing the same thing. It logs **promise pending** and then logs the entire response. If I had to return something and use it in another function I'll get only "promise pending" which s useless

Comment: In your `ageFinder` function, in the `catch` block, try adding `return {message: e.message || "AN ERROR OCCURRED"}`

Comment: So here's something weird. I wanted to use the function as a module in another file. So I just imported it to see how it works. Surprisingly, the module works as intended there.. I am confused

Comment: Did you `await` the result of your function where you imported it? Also, while running the snippet mentioned in your ques, did you pass some dummy value, and in your file which imports the module, you are passing a param to the function that you know is a valid `userName`? Would be helpful if you provided more details.

Comment: I did await yes

Comment: Calling it with another function worked thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

An `async` function always returns a promise. To use it you need to `await` it in another `async` function. If you do not want to `await` in another `async` function you may use it with the alternative `then` method. For example:

```
ageFinder("someUser")
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
}).
.catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: This worked just fine... The thing is I know async funcs always returns promises but I need a return value. console.log is ok but how do I get a return value. I have tried every way of using await